# How to add assets in Phalcon framework with Blade template engine?

Tags: php, assets, laravel-blade, phalcon, template-engine

A started to work with **Phalcon** framework, included **Blade** templating. It's already works, but unfortunately i didn't find the right way to include css and JS assets in master.blade.php.
If I add the assets like **$this->assets->addCss("css/bootstrap.min.css");** in the controller I can not include it in the master template file.

For example, my indexAction looks like this:

```
public function indexAction(){  
    $this->assets->addCss("css/bootstrap.min.css");
    $this->assets->addJs("js/bootstrap.min.js");
    return $this->blade->make('index.index');  
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - you should add blade as actual template engine into phalcon view.

Your class should `extends Engine implements EngineInterface`. If you will do it it could be nice to add it to incubator repository.

https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Mvc/View/Engine check out implementation of other engines for more how are they made. Then you could just do `{{ assets.outputJss() }}`, example from volt/twig, not sure how exactly it should look like in blade, never used it.

Also what's wrong with volt? It's faster than blade and have many features.

Comment: I heard that blade is better than Volt, because of this I wanted to do this. :) But now I think it was not a good idea. :) Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I am not telling it's a bad idea to use blade, but give a try to volt, then if you think it has some issues or it's not enough switch to other.

Comment: Now I decided to use volt instead of Blade. Blade is good, but I think volt is also good enough :) I'm new in both of these templating stuffs... :)